# Difference between variable and property scope in a script

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

My `__init__.py` script creates a panel that lets a user select the figure (typically a humanoid figure imported from Poser) she wants to give shaders to, defines the figure type and then sets the path to the image files used in the shader script.

The bit that creates the panel:

```
class MatShaderPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Create shaders for your Poser figure: Panel"""
    bl_label = "Figure Files Util"
    bl_idname = "MATERIALS_PT_shaders"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'

    def draw(self, context):
        # sets renderer to Cycles
        if bpy.context.scene.render.engine == 'BLENDER_RENDER':
            bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object

        row1 = layout.row()
        row1.label(text='Figure Name')

        row2 = layout.row()
        row2.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)
        row3 = layout.row()
        row3.prop(obj, "name")

        row4 = layout.row()
        row4.prop(context.scene, 'imag_path')
        row5 = layout.row()
        row5.operator("object.run_script", text='Apply Shaders')
        row5.enabled = context.scene.show_row5
```

I believe that I register that 'imag_path' property seen in row4.prop(context.scene, 'imag_path') in:

```
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.imag_path = bpy.props.StringProperty( \
      name="Images Path",
      default="",
      description="Defines the path to your images",
      subtype='DIR_PATH')
    bpy.types.Scene.figur_obj = bpy.props.StringProperty( \
      name="Figure Type",
      default="",
      description="Defines the base mesh name of your figure")

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.imag_path
    del bpy.types.Scene.figur_obj
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

However, the `imag_path` property doesn't appear to be available to the rest of the script. I was thinking of making it a global variable by setting it right after the import statements, but am not quite clear on whether that's the right approach. For example, this (in a subsequent function):

```
def shadersSetup():
    csvFile = imag_path + "/" + "image_List.csv"
```

...fails, as `imag_path` isn't available to `shaderSetup()`.

Think I need to read up on property scope vs variable scope and how all that relates to modules. [This](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/info_tutorial_addon.html) doesn't discuss it any.

#### **Update**

Not the full answer yet, so I can't call this solved, but I did incorporate both batFINGER's and TLousky's suggestions. Unfortunately, I am still getting an error based on what gets written to imag_path in that `DIR_PATH` property(?) which allows the user to go out and find the folder containing the images. I mean the last part of the resultant path looks exactly right, but the first bit seems not quite right, somehow: here is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/home/robyn/.config/blender/2.76/scripts/addons/make_Shaders/__init__.py", line 102, in execute
>           shadersSetup()
>         File "/home/robyn/.config/blender/2.76/scripts/addons/make_Shaders/__init__.py", line 124, in shadersSetup
>           iList = readImgList(csvFile)
>         File "/home/robyn/.config/blender/2.76/scripts/addons/make_Shaders/__init__.py", line 113, in readImgList
>           with open(fname, 'r') as csvfile:
>       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '//../../AllTextures/AllSkin/PS_Syri/image_list.csv'

The part of the path displayed is correct, exactly. But the script seems to expect a fully-qualified path. And I tried: `csvFile = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(scn.imag_path), "image_list.csv")`. Still gave me a truncated path.

I do want to say I thoroughly appreciate your help.

#### **2nd** **Update**

Since the problem with the path still exists, I've been running a series of test on this path issue, double-checking that the path and the file do indeed exist. I did change the csv_Path property to take the file name now:

```
bpy.types.Scene.csv_path = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="CSV Path",
  default="*.csv",
  maxlen=1024,
  description="CSV location",
  subtype='FILE_PATH')
```

Mind you, I thought by doing a default="*.csv", it would only display that csv file in the folder, but it displays all files.

Here is the path testing code:

```
scn = bpy.context.scene
csvFile = os.path.abspath(scn.csv_path)
csvPath = csvFile[:-14]
fullyQP = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), csvFile)
print("scn.csv_path: " + scn.csv_path)
print("csvFile: " + csvFile)
print("csvPath: " + csvPath)
print("Joined cwd and the CSV: " + fullyQP)
print(os.path.isdir(csvPath))
```

Here is the output to the print()s:

```
scn.csv_path: //../../AllTextures/AllSkin/PS_Syri/image_List.csv
csvFile: //AllTextures/AllSkin/PS_Syri/image_List.csv
csvPath: //AllTextures/AllSkin/PS_Syri/
Joined cwd and the CSV: //AllTextures/AllSkin/PS_Syri/image_List.csv
False
```

The last is most significant, as it is not seeing that *relative* *path* as a workable path. In my preferences, under File, I have Relative Paths ticked. I'm completely baffled as to how to proceed.

ETA: I guess if I can't get this working, I might need to have the users put those csv files (and image files) where Blender and the script can easily find them. Thing is: what I was hoping was that they could use existing folders somewhere in their /runtime/textures/character directories instead of having to make a copy to their Blender projects folders.

Comment: Don't think you'll get away with changing properties in the draw method of a panel, in your case the render engine.  Also using `os.path.join(scene.imag_path, "image_list.csv")` is good practice.

Comment: You were right, batFINGER... changed to Blender Internal and the If statement failed. Working in the function further down (shaderSetup()) which is where it should have been. Also, added os.path.join()  - thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26898/how-to-create-a-folder-dialog/26906#26906

Comment: Is the filename image_list.csv or image_List.csv if you're on linux it's case sensitive.  Also do you need the csv file, you can select multiple files from the filebrowser http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?164765-Scripting-examples-for-2-5-update-Mar-26th-2010&p=1975106&viewfull=1#post1975106 or if you do why not make the string_prop a FILE_PATH and pick the csv file itself.

Comment: Your suggestion makes good sense, batFINGER, for a number of reasons, paramount of which being: if a .csv hasn't been created, selecting the folder only will still cause the script to fail. I should be able to get the location of the files from that.

Comment: I've gone ahead and implemented your suggestions, @ poor, but the problem persists: Blender will not recognise a relative path as a valid one, but will see a fully qualified path as valid. Not sure if this is okay, but so that it can be viewed in its entirety, I've posted it to my [github-unstable site](https://github.com/robinboncoeur/Shaders-Addon/tree/unstable).

Comment: @RobinsSea Sorry for the delay, but I did not received any message. Probably because of the whitespace between the 'at' and the name. Anyway, paths needs to be valid :) All you need is `os.join()`, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918682/concatenate-path-platform-independent and avoid somthing like `path[:3]` in order to write platform independent python. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Also important to know: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12152/absolute-path-of-files-in-blender-with-python

Comment: @poor thanks for the tip on leaving out the space. My path-to-csv is created by the user navigating to the file (so it - and the related images referenced in the csv - can be anywhere on the drive, not just in the same folder as the .blend. Therefore, although in my case the images are in a subfolder which is in the same Projects folder that holds the the .blend, that may not be the case for the user. os.path.abspath( path-to-csv ) returns: /home/robyn/Documents/Blender/Projects/AllScripts/Shader_blend/../../AllTextures/AllSkin/PS_Syri/image_List.csv - not valid: it includes the .blend. :-/

Comment: @poor I do want to thank you for looking at this. I've updated my git to have a [testing branch](https://github.com/robinboncoeur/Shaders-Addon/tree/testing) which has the full code - I did use  ideasman's example, but I'm convinced I'm missing something.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say: bpy.path.abspath( path-to-csv ) returns: /home/robyn/Documents/Blender/Projects/AllScripts/Shader_blend/../../AllTextures‌​/AllSkin/PS_Syri/image_List.csv

Answer (score 1):

When you add a property to the scene type, such as with your `bpy.types.Scene.imag_path`, you need to access it through a scene object.

For instance:

```
print( bpy.context.scene.imag_path )
```

Or in your case:

```
def shadersSetup():
    csvFile = bpy.context.scene.imag_path + "/" + "image_List.csv"
```

You actually have used it this way in another part of your code, which gave away the hint:

```
row4.prop(context.scene, 'imag_path')
```

Comment: IMO using a property group makes most sense and is easier to manage: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26898/how-to-create-a-folder-dialog/26906#26906

Comment: I agree. Also with  batFINGER's comment from above advising to use os.path.join as a safer, platform independent way to concatenate paths.

Comment: @TLousky - As this script is to be platform-independent, I will definitely include this approach. @ poor - I've had a look at [the script](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26898/how-to-create-a-folder-dialog/26906#26906) you linked to: thank you for the heads up and the suggestion. Whilst running the script from text editor was simple and didn't require using properties, I think your approach might be needed to manage material_slots for a figure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to close this question (which totally became more of a path issue than anything else) by saying that os.path.join() works in this context: by placing the files you wish to access in the same folder as the .blend, and then using bpy.data.filepath:

```
blendPath = bpy.data.filepath
blendDir = os.path.dirname(blendPath)
csv_file_path = os.path.join(blendDir, "path_List.csv")
```

blendDir is the fully-qualified path to the currently opened .blend, in which directory the path_List.csv will also reside.